# Imploding a list for use in a Python MySQL IN clause

Tags: python, mysql

I know how to map a list to a string:

```python
foostring = ",".join( map(str, list_of_ids) )
```

And I know that I can use the following to get that string into an IN clause:

```python
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN ('%s')" % (foostring))
```

How can I accomplish the same thing *safely* (avoiding [SQL injection](https://SQL%20injection)) using a MySQL database?

In the above example, because foostring is not passed as an argument to execute, it is vulnerable. I also have to quote and escape outside of the MySQL library.

(There is a [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315672/automagically-expanding-a-python-list-with-formatted-output), but the answers listed there either do not work for MySQL database or are vulnerable to SQL injection.)

Comment: You might be able to get some inspiration from a similar question that is done in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list/327384

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list in sql query as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

Comment: @mluebke Any idea about passing multiple lists in query?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Use the `list_of_ids` directly:

```python
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(list_of_ids))
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN (%s)" % format_strings,
                tuple(list_of_ids))
```

That way you avoid having to quote yourself, and avoid all kinds of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Note that the data (`list_of_ids`) is going directly to MySQL's driver, as a parameter (not in the query text) so there isn't any injection. You can leave any characters you want in the string; there isn't any need to remove or quote characters.

Comment: @heikogerlach: I am not quoting the %s... The first line creates a string of "%s,%s,%s"... the same size of list_of_ids length.

Comment: Will this work in sqlite also?
Cause I just tried it and it seems to point out syntax errors.

Comment: @Sohaib in sqlite the replacement char is `?` not `%s` so it would work if you change the first line to `format_strings = ','.join('?' * len(list_of_ids))`.

Comment: Depending on how often such a statement is used with different number of arguments I like to group the argument number and execute multiple to make sure the database only sees a limited number of variations (for the sql cache).this also helps against too many arguments.

Comment: Could you give an example syntax for the same solution in Python3?

Comment: @nosklo How'd you do the same if you are using the query object which has parameters
for e.g
`fname_list = ['item1', 'item2']
query = ("select distinct cln from vcf_commits where branch like %s and repository like %s and filename in (%s) and author not like %s" % format_strings,)
cursor = churn_db_connection.get_connection_cursor()
cursor.execute(query, (branch, repository, tuple(fname_list), invalid_author,))`
this throws an error

Comment: @kdas in your case you don't want the `% format_strings` part to change the other `%s` placeholders in your query, only the `IN (%s)` placeholder - The way to achieve this is to double all `%` chars except the one you want to replace: `query = ("select distinct cln from vcf_commits where branch like %%s and repository like %%s and filename in (%s) and author not like %%s" % format_strings,); cursor.execute(query, (branch, repository) + tuple(fname_list) + (invalid_author,))`

Comment: Aah this is brilliant @nosklo. The comma (,) after format_strings was causing error but after removing that it works flawlessly. Genius. Applause.
`query = ("select distinct cln from vcf_commits where branch like %%s and repository like %%s and filename in (%s) and author not like %%s" % format_strings);`

Comment: Modifying @nosklo answer to use f strings.                                                     `format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(list_of_ids)) 
cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN ({format_strings})", tuple(list_of_ids))`

Comment: I could not make this solution work with two open parameters (ie. one IN(...) and another WHERE clause) This solution from another thread helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284244/pass-list-values-to-mysql-query-using-python/59284517#59284517

Answer (score 14):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysql-in-clause/589416#589416) gets messy when we have a lot of the parameters or if we want to use named parameters.

After some trials,

```py
ids = [5, 3, ...]  # List of ids
cursor.execute('''
SELECT
...
WHERE
  id IN %(ids)s
  AND created_at > %(start_dt)s
''', {
  'ids': tuple(ids), 'start_dt': '2019-10-31 00:00:00'
})
```

It was kested with Python 2.7 and pymysql 0.7.11.

Comment: This does not work with python 3 and mysql-connector-python 8.0.21. An error "Python tuple cannot be converted to MySQL type" is returned.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to still be a problem with Python3 in 2021, as pointed out in the comment by Rubms to the answer by markk.

Adding about 9 lines of code to the method "_process_params_dict" in "cursor.py" in the mysql connector package to handle tuples solved the problem for me:

```
def _process_params_dict(self, params):
    """Process query parameters given as dictionary"""
    try:
        to_mysql = self._connection.converter.to_mysql
        escape = self._connection.converter.escape
        quote = self._connection.converter.quote
        res = {}
        for key, value in list(params.items()):
            if type(value) is tuple: ### BEGIN MY ADDITIONS
                res[key.encode()] = b''
                for subvalue in value:
                    conv = subvalue
                    conv = to_mysql(conv)
                    conv = escape(conv)
                    conv = quote(conv)
                    res[key.encode()] = res[key.encode()] + b',' + conv if len(res[key.encode()]) else conv
            else: ### END MY ADDITIONS
                conv = value
                conv = to_mysql(conv)
                conv = escape(conv)
                conv = quote(conv)
                res[key.encode()] = conv
    except Exception as err:
        raise errors.ProgrammingError(
            "Failed processing pyformat-parameters; %s" % err)
    else:
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the question, but I stumbled upon a similar problem, but I wanted to use a dict of named parameters instead of a tuple (because if I want to modify the parameters to add or remove some, I don't want to re-construct the tuple, messing the order can be very easy and bug-inducing...).

My solution was to format the query string to explode the parameter into several parameters, and then construct the parameter dict with these new params:

```
from typing import Iterable

query = """
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (%(test_param)s)
"""

parameters = {"test_param": [1, 2, 3])

new_params = {}

for k, v in parameters.items():
    if isinstance(v, Iterable):
        iterable_params = {f"{k}_{i}": value for i, value in enumerate(v)}
        iterable_params_formatted = [f"%({k}_{i})s" for i in range(0, len(v))]
        query = query.replace(f"%({k})s", ", ".join(iterable_params_formatted))
        new_params.update(iterable_params)
    else:
        new_params[k] = v

print(query)
print(new_params)
```

Result:

```
> SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (%(test_param_0)s, %(test_param_1)s, %(test_param_2)s)

> {'test_param_0': 1, 'test_param_1': 2, 'test_param_2': 3}
```

Could be done better, but I couldn't find a solution using a dict of named parameters instead of an ordered tuple.

Answer (score -3):

If you use Django 2.0 or 2.1 and Python 3.6, this is the right way:

```
from django.db import connection
RESULT_COLS = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
RESULT_COLS_STR = ', '.join(['a.'+'`'+i+'`' for i in RESULT_COLS])
QUERY_INDEX = RESULT_COLS[0]

TABLE_NAME = 'test'
search_value = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']  # <-- a list
query = (
    f'SELECT DISTINCT {RESULT_COLS_STR} FROM {TABLE_NAME} a '
    f'WHERE a.`{RESULT_COLS[0]}` IN %s '
    f'ORDER BY a.`{RESULT_COLS[0]}`;'
)  # <- 'SELECT DISTINCT a.`col1`, a.`col2`, a.`col3` FROM test a WHERE a.`col1` IN %s ORDER BY a.`col1`;'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query, params=[search_value])  # parameters is a list with a list as its element
```

#### References

- *[How to pass a list of values for an `in` SQL clause in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887559/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-for-an-in-sql-clause-in-django/23891759#23891759)*
- *[Passing parameters into raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)*

Answer (score -3):

yet another way.

```
myList = [
  "this","andthis","butalsothis","anddontforgetaboutthis"
]

myListStr = '"' + '","'.join(myList) + '"'


query = (
            ' SELECT'
            '  col1,'
            '  col2,'
            '  col3
            ' FROM'
            '  myTable'
            ' WHERE'
            '   col3 IN ('+ myListStr +')'
          )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.  Also, share what makes you think that this solution is safe in terms of SQL injection (as requested by mluebke)

Answer (score -4):

Use:

```
list_of_ids = [ 1, 2, 3]
query = "select * from table where x in %s" % str(tuple(list_of_ids))
print query
```

This could work for some use cases if you don't wish to be concerned with the method in which you have to pass arguments to complete the query string and would like to invoke just `cursror.execute(query)`.

Another way could be:

```
"select * from table where x in (%s)" % ', '.join(str(id) for id in list_of_ids)
```

Answer (score -4):

Though this question is quite old. I am sharing my solution if it can help someone.

`list_to_check = ['A', 'B']
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN ({})".format(str(list_to_check)[1:-1])`

Tested with `Python=3.6`

Comment: I am afraid this solution is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, as the provided `list_to_check` is not being SQL-escaped. This is why passing the values as parameters to `execute` is more appropriate. Use this solution very carefully (that is, the input IDs are not received as parameters from the outside of your application), as someone could use this to attack your system and access your database.

Answer (score -5):

Another simple solution using [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python):

```python
# Creating a new list of strings and convert to tuple
sql_list = tuple([ key.encode("UTF-8") for key in list_of_ids ])

# Replace "{}" with "('id1','id2',...'idlast')"
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN {}".format(sql_list))
```

Comment: Please share how this solution is safe in terms of SQL injection

Answer (score -11):

Very simple: Just use the below formation

```
rules_id = ["9","10"]

sql1 = "SELECT * FROM attendance_rules_staff WHERE id in(" + ", ".join(map(str, rules_id)) + ")"
```

Note:

```
", ".join(map(str, rules_id))
```

Comment: Where does it do sql quoting and isn’t this using a literal instead of bind variables?

Comment: Do not need , it simply working fine. You can test
Because tuple formation directly converted as string with first braces ("9", "10") . Which adjust sql formation. So you do not need other formation to make is sql adjastable

Comment: and if an `rules_id` contains `"); DROP TABLES Bobby --`?

Comment: Already told "imploding a list" not ") ... so before query you need to validate

Comment: or use:                                    
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM attendance_rules_staff WHERE id in("+", ".join(map(str, rules_id))+")"

Comment: I guess its fine if you stick to numbers, but still it produces a SQL with literals, poor SQL parser...