# Delete whole hierarchy with sqlalchemy polymorphic relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I want to delete some elements in tables that have a polymorphic relationship in sqlalchemy. Here's the model:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'employee'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(50))
  type = Column(String(50))

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
    'polymorphic_on':type
  }

class Engineer(Employee):
  __tablename__ = 'engineer'
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
  engineer_name = Column(String(30))

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
  }
```

And here's how I delete it:

```
e = Engineer();
e.name = "John";
e.engineer_name = "Doe";
DBSession.add(e);

q = session.query(Engineer).filter(Employee.name == "John")

q.delete(False)
```

I get the following error, is that a bug or am I doing it the wrong way ?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
column: employee.name [SQL: u'DELETE FROM engineer WHERE employee.name
= ?'] [parameters: ('John',)]
```

I'm expecting sqlalchemy to delete the entres in the engineer and employee tables.

Comment: should it not be `q = session.query(Engineer).filter(Engineer.name == "John")`? (instead of `Employee.name`)

Answer (score 5):

First you should define the on delete behaviour of this relationship:

```
id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
```

Then, using the ORM, you can delete all engineers with name "John" through a loop:

```
eng_list = session.query(Engineer).filter(Employee.name == "John").all()

for eng in eng_list:
   session.delete(eng)
session.commit()
```

This will delete the records from both the `Employee` and `Engineer` tables.

**update**: comment on error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such 
column: employee.name [SQL: u'DELETE FROM engineer WHERE employee.name
= ?'] [parameters: ('John',)]
```

Your attempt tries to Delete from Engineer with a join to Employee (to access the field Employee.name). But this join is missing from the query sqlalchemy is emitting to the backend.

I don't think SQLite supports deleting with joins. Perhaps you can try to run `session.query(Engineer).filter(Employee.name == "John").delete()` against a different backend, and sqlalchemy **may** be able to emit the proper SQL statement. I haven't tried it though.

**update 2:** On backends that respect foreign key constraints (and the `onupdate` constraint has been set to `cascade`), it should be sufficient to delete the row in the parent row, and the linked rows in the child will automatically be deleted.

I tried this example with both MySQL & Postgresql backends, and the following query deleted the row from both tables (`employee` & `engineer`):

```
session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.name=='John').delete()
```

For some reason, on Sqlite, this only deletes the record from `employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Because doing the joined `DELETE` is not supported directly, I found an easy workaround is to use your normal joined query to select the ids to delete, then pass those ids to a separate `DELETE` query.

One minor annoyance is that since your returned ids are integers you would likely run into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583706/python-warning-truncated-incorrect-double-value) like I did if you try to pass those ids (technically an array of tuples) directly to the `DELETE` query. A simple intermediate conversion to strings fixes that.

So all together:

```
ids_to_delete = session.query(Engineer.id). \
    filter(Employee.name == "John"). \
    all()

# Convert the resulting int tuples to simple strings:
id_strings = [str(id_[0]) for id_ in ids_to_delete]

session.query(Engineer). \
    filter(Engineer.id.in_(id_strings)). \
    delete(synchronize_session=False)
```