# WHERE IN Clause in python list

Tags: python, mysql

I need to pass a batch of parameters to mysql in python. Here is my code:

```
sql = """ SELECT * from my_table WHERE name IN (%s) AND id=%(Id)s AND puid=%(Puid)s"""

params = {'Id':id,'Puid'  : pid}
in_p=', '.join(list(map(lambda x: '%s', names)))
sql = sql %in_p

cursor.execute(sql, names) #todo: add params to sql clause
```

The problem is I want to pass the name list to sql IN clause, meanwhile I also want to pass the id and puid as parameters to the sql query clause. How do I implement these in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about the arguments to `cursor.execute` that you want. You want to ultimately execute

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name IN (%s, %s, %s) AND id = %s AND puid = %s;", ["name1", "name2", "name3", id, pid])
```

How do you get there? The tricky part is getting the variable number of `%s`s right in the `IN` clause. The solution, as you probably saw from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574647/341730) is to dynamically build it and %-format it into the string.

```
in_p = ', '.join(list(map(lambda x: '%s', names)))
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name IN (%s) AND id = %s AND puid = %s;" % in_p
```

But this doesn't work. You get:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

It looks like Python is confused about the second two `%s`s, which you don't want to replace. The solution is to tell Python to treat those `%s`s differently by escaping the `%`:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name IN (%s) AND id = %%s AND puid = %%s;" % in_p
```

Finally, to build the arguments and execute the query:

```
args = names + [id, pid]
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks univerio. But one more question, what if  my args is a map like this:
args = names + {'tid':id, 'tpid':pid}
Does it also works?

Comment: @Jensz Why don't you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work. python raise error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list

Comment: @Jensz Right. You can't add a `list` and `dict` together.

Comment: If I could upvote this ten times I would.  Thanks.  This is the best explanation of what must be a common use case.

Answer (score -1):

```
sql = """ SELECT * from my_table WHERE name IN (%s) AND id=%(Id)s AND puid=%(Puid)s""".replace("%s", "%(Clause)s")
print sql%{'Id':"x", 'Puid': "x", 'Clause': "x"}
```

This can help you.