# Check for multiple values exists in database in MySQLdb python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

My requirement is to check if there are entries in a table matching a list of values for a column. I am using the following query:

```
insert_enquiry =  """SELECT P_ID,Jobname FROM build_table WHERE Build_number IN %s;""" % insert_constraint
```

insert_constraint here is a list of numbers. Build_number is a column which has integers. If I try to execute this query using:

```
cursor.execute(insert_enquiry)
```

I get the following error:

```
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[184, 931, 1005, 1070, 165, 99, 365, 930, 164, 98' at line 1
```

I believe this is because of the square brackets that appear in the list. I tried to remove them by converting the list to string, but then I get the same error as now the integer list is converted to a string.

I have also tried the following syntax:

```
insert_enquiry =  """SELECT P_ID,Jobname FROM product_build WHERE Build_number IN %s;"""
cursor.executemany(insert_enquiry, insert_constraint)
```

This give the following error:

```
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '184' at line 1
```

Edit:

```
insert_enquiry =  """SELECT P_ID,Jobname FROM product_build WHERE Build_number IN (%s);"""
cursor.executemany(insert_enquiry, insert_constraint)
```

This takes only the last element in the list insert_constraint for some reason.

Comment: Isn't it **IN(...)** instead of **IN[...]** ?

Comment: Yes, I have made an edit to the questions. It somehow take the last element in the list insert_constraint and skips all the elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574647/4077331.

The idea was to add `len(insert_constraint)` number of `%s` to the query string. By doing this, the query will accept a list for the `WHERE IN` clause

```
insert_enquiry =  "SELECT build_number,jobname FROM %s WHERE build_number IN (%s);"
insert_enquiry_string =', '.join(map(lambda x: '%s', insert_constraint_build_num))
insert_enquiry = insert_enquiry % (table_name, insert_enquiry_string)
cursor.execute(insert_enquiry, insert_constraint_build_num)
```

This solved the issue.