# How to assign array as a variable in PostgreSQL select statement?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am facing problem in writing PostgreSQL select statement in Python when I have to pass more than one values in a statement. Below is the sample example.

```
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine

 values = [ 'a' , 'b' ]

 con = create_engine(conn_string)

 results = con.execute( "select * from table where var in (%s)", [ values ] )
```

I am able to run query with single value but getting format error for an array.

Comment: In the case of the duplicate, you need to change `?` to `%s` since postgres uses different placeholders, but the principle is identical.

Comment: If you're using psycopg2 as your DB-API driver, you could pass it a tuple as the argument and it'll form a suitable form for the IN operator: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation. No need to manually create comma separated placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in stackoverflow . It is a duplicate question. i was overthinking because of postgresql.

[Executing “SELECT … WHERE … IN …” using MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574609/executing-select-where-in-using-mysqldb)