# How to pass a list of *columns* to MySQLDb execute

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

It's possible to [pass a `tuple` to MySQLdb for use in an `IN` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416), but is it possible to pass a `tuple` for use as a column list? This doesn't work:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM users", tuple(columns))
OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

It seems like `execute` does not do syntax-aware replacement of lists.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If there's a duplicate it would be nice to know. And if this is a terrible idea which should always be avoided it would definitely be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but functional:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT %s FROM users" % \
    ', '.join('`' + MySQLdb.escape_string(column) + '`' for column in columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with what you are trying to do here, firstly lets look at what the tuple would look like:

```
>>> columns = ['a','b','c']
>>> tuple(columns)
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>>
```

As you can see the tuple will contain the same number of elements as your list, but in your query you on have a single %s. Hence the column count issue. Secondly if you added the correct number of %s the cursor would translate the elements to strings and escape them:

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT %s,%s,%s FROM a", tuple(columns))
2L
>>> cur.fetchall()
(('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'))
>>>
```

And you would receive the literals back as values and not column names as expected. I don't believe in this instance using the parameter option is going to be able to produce the results you expect.

A possible way would be to create your query using standard string methods:

```
>>> query = "SELECT %s FROM a" % ",".join(columns)
>>> query
'SELECT a,b,c FROM a'
>>>
```

And then pass this query to the cursor.