# How to pass a list of values for an `in` SQL clause in Django

Tags: database, django, django-orm

I need to use a raw SQL query in a Django app I am writing. The SQL query contains an `in` clause in the `where` statement:

```
select *
from abc_mymodel
where some_fk in (1,2,3)
and some_status = 'foo'
```

I am a big proponent of passing SQL params as parameters. This is easily done for the single value ones. However, I am not sure how (or if) this can be done for `in` clauses. Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
sql = """
    select *
    from abc_mymodel
    where some_fk in %s
    and some_status = %s
"""
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_status = 'foo'
trinkets = MyModel.objects.raw(
    sql,
    params=(my_list, my_status)
)
```

I know I can use string composition to write the `in` clause and use params for the remaining values. However, I am curious if it is possible to use params for `in` clauses as well.

Comment: This question asks explicitly for a raw sql query, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation on `raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw),

> `params` is a **list or dictionary** of parameters. You’ll use `%s` placeholders in the query string for a list... Such **placeholders will be replaced with parameters from the params argument.**

Conveniently, raw queries are very easy to test in a Django shell. If you simply input your `raw()` query, it will print a `RawQuerySet` with your resulting query:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> pk_list = (1, 3, 6)
>>> User.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id IN %s', params=[pk_list])
<RawQuerySet: 'SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id IN (1, 3, 6)'>
```

As you can see, whatever is in `params` is placed into the raw query. In your example, you need to change `my_list` to a tuple (or else it will look like "*IN [1,2,3]*") and change your `params` input to a list (`params=[my_list, my_status]`).

Comment: I always forget to turn the list into a tuple, thank you!

Comment: Note, this does not work for tuples of only one item. The string output is in the python format (34,) which SQL will choke on.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way for Django ORM type querying:

```
list = [1,2,3]
choices = Model.objects.filter(columnName__in=list)
```

In your case:

```
list = [1,2,3]
choices = abc_mymodel.objects.filter(some_fk__in=list)
```

Comment: That's not quite what i was asking about. I needed a way to do this with raw SQL queries.

Comment: I came here looking for this.