# Raw sql query issue in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to to make an SQL query to impliment the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72384995/4180276).

The user suggested I try doing a raw sql query to solve.  I am having issues implimenting what he suggests.

For example, this is what I have so far.

```py
ingredients = ["eggs", "bacon", "salt"]
recipes = Recipe.objects.raw('select whattocook_RecipeIngredients \
    from whattocook_Recipe a \
    inner join whattocook_RecipeIngredients b \
    on a.id = b.recipe_id and b.ingredient in (ingedients) \
    group by recipeingredients \
    having count(*) >= 2')
```

But this does not work.  His answer says to do this

```py
recipe_list = Recipe.objects.raw('select a.*
   from app_Recipe a 
   inner join app_RecipeIngredients b
      on a.id = b.recipe_id and b.ingredient in ("egg", "bacon", "rice")
   group by a.*
   having count(*) >= 2')

maybe replace app_ with your project name, replace a.* with list of column names.
```

So I think I am misunderstanding which columns I need to replace, given my code gives me this error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "ingedients" does not exist
LINE 1: ...       on a.id = b.recipe_id and b.ingredient in (ingedients...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "b.ingredient".
```

My app is named whattocook, and the models are as follows

```py
class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ingredient = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
class Recipe(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to=MEDIA_URL, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    preptime = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cookingtime = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cookingtimeoptions = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    preptimeoptions = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    servings = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    rating_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: There are two good answers here (one for raw queries, one for using a filter with a "normal" django command with filtering): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887559/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-for-an-in-sql-clause-in-django

It is probably bad form to just ask your question again because you didn't like the original answer, but I will note that you haven't spelled your variable names right (which is one thing) but you still can't just type a variable name into a raw sql statement - so as a rule you need to provide parameters which is how sql deals with variable inputs.

Comment: @topsail I agree although I this case I was unable to answer despite a few tries, also helps to know it can be done via the ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with:

```
from django.db.models import Count
ingredients = ["eggs", "bacon", "rice"]
Recipe.objects.filter(
    recipeingredients__ingredient__in=ingredients
).alias(
    ningredient=Count('recipeingredients')
).filter(
    ningredient__gte=len(ingredients)
)
```

Comment: This seems to work, one question.  The `ningredient__gte=2` if the ingredients vary, that number needs to change? So if say it is a list of 20 ingredients, that would be 19?

Comment: @nadermx: we first filter on the list of ingredients (`['egg', 'bacon', 'rice']`, so `ningredient` is the number of *matched* ingredients, and thus here it can only be at most three.

Comment: @nadermx: but if you have 20 ingredients, and it should match *all*, you should indeed use 20.

Comment: Thank you, is this case sensative in the search too?

Comment: @nadermx: yes, so `'egg'`, will *not* match `'Egg'` or `'EGG'`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this search case insensative? Also I edited the answer to make it more dynamic.  Thank you

Comment: I presume I replace the `ìn` with `icontains` in this query `recipeingredients__ingredient__in=ingredients`