# using "in" inside sql raw query in python with parameter

Tags: python, mysql, sql

i have to pass more than one id's to my sql raw query and these id's will be passed as parameter.
i am doing this in following way :

```
itlist=[6009,[5989,5796,5793],5788,5750]
for it in itlist:
    cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id in (%d);"%[it])
    data1=cursor.fetchall()
        for record in data1:
            print record[0]
```

this gives me an error, i dont know how to pass that list to the sql query.
any help will be appreciated...thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? Can you edit your question to include a partial stack trace?

Comment: i am doing it in django and on browser it shows me an error : unboundLocalError..

Comment: may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause

Comment: Part of your trouble is the nested lists you're passing.  There's no way that's going to result in a valid query.

Comment: and using a list with the `%d` formatter will give you a `TypeError` ...

Comment: I think OP is attempting multiple queries, and when the item in the list is not itself a list, OP tries to put it into a list before passing it into the query. Of course, this breaks when the item is already a list.

Comment: so, how to do this?, and my list data is of int type not str...

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/… –  Haim Evg
it takes the input as string but my numbers are of integer type

Comment: i can do this in following way ...simply using python basics :
cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id=(select max(id) from builds where id in ("+ str(it)[1:-1] +"));")

Answer (score 0):

flatten the list into a newlist and pass this to your query:

```
def flatten(foo):
    newl = []
    for x in foo:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
            for y in flatten(x):
                 newl.append(y)
        else:
            newl.append(x)
    return newl

itlist=[6009,[5989,5796,5793],5788,5750]
newitlist = flatten(itlist)

for it in newitlist:
    cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id in (%d);"%[it])
    data1=cursor.fetchall()
        for record in data1:
            print record[0]
```

Comment: i dont want to use every id as individual, i have to pass a list as it as if a list found in itlist, and in that case raw query has 3 values inside the "in" clause, otherwise single, as given in the example...

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416/2297365) Haim referenced, but for your particular case where you have nested lists:

```
itlist=[6009,[5989,5796,5793],5788,5750]
for it in itlist:
    # This ensures that 'it' is a list even if it is just a single element
    if type(it) != list:
        it = [it]
    format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(it))
    cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id in (%s)" % format_strings,
            tuple(it))
    data1=cursor.fetchall()
        for record in data1:
            print record[0]
```

The reason why there's a `%s` in the query string and not a `%d` is because you're actually going to replace it with a bunch of `%s`'s (so `%s` or `%s,%s,%s`) in order to accommodate the variable number of id's you're trying to pass in.

So in your case, the first query string that would be built is:

```
"select branch_tag from builds where id in (6009)"
```

And the next one would be:

```
"select branch_tag from builds where id in (5989,5796,5793)"
```

This is all, of course, assuming that `itlist` is meant to be nested as in your question. If it isn't, then most of this answer still applies as:

```
itlist=[6009,5989,5796,5793,5788,5750]
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(itlist))
cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id in (%s)" % format_strings,
        tuple(itlist))
data1=cursor.fetchall()
    for record in data1:
        print record[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

convert the every element to a list and then just use the python basics in following way :

```
itlist=[[6009],[5989,5796,5793],[5750]]
for it in itlist:
    cursor.execute("select branch_tag from builds where id=(select max(id) from builds        where id in ("+ str(it)[1:-1] +"));")
data1=cursor.fetchall()
for record in data1:
    print record[0]
```

Thanx all for your feedbacks and your valuable time.