# passing many arguments to one placeholder of django cursor (placeholer in IN)

Tags: python, sql, django, placeholder

I mean something like this:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable where id IN (%s)', [params])
```

Parameters can not be just iterable - it doesn't work.
Cannot be also in CSV format due escaping value by db handler.

How to use placeholder within `IN` ?

---

By CSV is wrong, I mean that for `params=['1','2','3','4','5']`

```
c.execute('select * from mytable where id in (%s)', [','.join(params)])
```

will produce:

```
select * from mytable where id  in ('1,2,3,4,5')
```

but correct sql is:

```
select * from mytable where id  in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

and it seems to be hard to achieve with placeholders.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'it cannot be in CSV format'. IN expects a list of values, which necessarily must be separated by a comma. If your `params` are a list, you should do something like `','.join(params)`. That will convert a list like `[1, 2, 3]` into a string like `1,2,3`.

Comment: Be careful using `%s`  as a placeholder in SQl, it can leave you vulnerable to an SQL injection https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Chris_Rands: it's not about dummy `"%s" % params`.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: why are you querying with a cursor if you are using django??

Comment: @e4c5: .. because building complex and optimized and readable query in django ORM is a pain in ... . I have many cases in project which requires joining 10-30 mysql tables and using extra functions or aggregations. Much faster is achieve it in plain SQL than django, especially when you need have it optimized and readable (for debug purspose at least)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `IN` for this since indeed, in expects a sequence of ints, but the ORM translates a list to an `ARRAY`, and if you use `join` you'll end up with a string.

The solution is to use the equivalent `ANY`. The formatting is slightly different, but this should work for you:

```
c.execute('select * from mytable where id = ANY(%s)', [params])
```

Given `params = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the resulting SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where id = ANY(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Note that this requires the list of ids to be made up of ints, so if you have a list of strings be sure to convert them first.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**
Sorry about the older answer. This should work as you want, but might not be the best solution. I tried it with both, params as a list of strings and a list of integers.

```
from django.db import connection

params = [1, 2, 3, '4', '5']
placeholders = ('%s,'*len(params)).rstrip(',')  # Having a comma at the end will give a syntax error

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable where id IN ({})'.format(placeholders), params)
    #  Use the cursor here
```

**End updated answer**

---

In SQL the value for `IN` needs to be a comma separated list

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

<strike>So the simplest approach for you, assuming that params is an iterable would be</strike>

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable where id IN (%s)', [', '.join(params)])
```

The join will convert your iterable params into a comma separated string which will then replace the %s.

Generally you will want your query params to be escaped. Even the data you stored should be escaped.

**Edit:** Also notice that I have moved your cursor into a `with` block. You should always close your connections. [Read up more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors).

Answer (score -2):

Solution is rather simple:

`c.execute('select * from mytable where id in (%s)' % (','.join(params),))`

See similar topic:
[imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

Comment: yes, it is, but above don't use cursor placeholder - it's rather workaround. However, it's possible with MySql db handler using named parameters in formatting query, but unobtainable with django db handler.

Comment: Please be aware, this is ACTIVELY DANGEROUS. By using normal string formatting you are introducing an SQL Injection attack vector, especially if params are from any form of user left data. Do not, under any circumstances, use this code.

Comment: Yikes, dont use string interpolation!!!!! This i the #1 way stuff gets hacked!!!