# How to fetch data in loop in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, maya

I have a list and i want to pass all value of list to the where condition of Query.I am using This in Maya Python script Editor using maya cmds

**code**

```
list = [1,2,3]
db = MySQLdb.connect("host","root","password","test" )  
for num in list:             
   cursor = db.cursor()
   cursor.execute('select  Name from project WHERE projectID = %s '%(num))
   name  = cursor.fetchone() 
   print(name)      
   cursor.close()
```

**Error**

> Error: ProgrammingError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py line 38: 1064 #

Comment: Right, it should be `cursor.execute('select ...', (num,))`

Comment: I think part of error message is missing. Seems like a syntax error, can you verify table and field names? Also, given that the list is ints I would give a try to: `cursor.execute('select Name from project WHERE ProjectID = %d;' % (num))`

Comment: If you feel that the duplicate target does not answer your question, then please include the full traceback of the error, not just a truncated snippet.

Comment: i have already given full snippet of error.I am using this code in maya 2014 @IljaEverilä Everilä

Comment: Your question's first part is strongly related to, if not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause. That "snipper of error" is almost next to useless without the traceback (and the rest of the error message). Note that if those credentials you edited out were real, they're still visible in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
   `cursor.executemany('select Name from project WHERE ProjectID = %s', list)` without the for loop.

Doing so will be better for your performance, as the database won't be used in every for loop, just once.

Also avoid calling things list, tuple etc.

Comment: @Barmar Damn, I'm blind and missed it's `executemany()`. But in that case it should be a sequence of param sequences... Also did MySQLdb support multiple result sets with `executemany()`?

Comment: Convert it to a list of tuples. 
More here:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Comment: A note about `executemany()` from the [DB-API 2.0 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany): "Use of this method for an operation which produces one or more result sets constitutes undefined behavior, and the implementation is permitted (but not required) to raise an exception when it detects that a result set has been created by an invocation of the operation."