# Python string formatting on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I'm trying to execute a query using two parameters, one is a list and the other is a number.

Here is my code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT cod_art, price_EU, price_third_country 
                FROM lt_gamma_articles 
                WHERE cod_art in (%s) AND cod_store = %d 
                ORDER BY cod_art, timestamp" 
             % format_strings, tuple(cod_art_int), int(shop) )
```

I get this error:

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I think the error is in the string formatting, but I don't know how to format it correctly and I've been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of your code, I'm gussing your basing it off of [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416/369450). Assuming that's the case, and
*format_strings* is built similar to:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(cod_art_int))
```

I would use [.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to build the query string, and build up a list for the positional query parameters:

```
query_params = list(cod_art_int)
query_params.append(int(shop))

query_sql = """
  SELECT cod_art, price_EU, price_third_country 
  FROM lt_gamma_articles
  WHERE cod_art IN ({cod_art_list}) AND cod_store = %s 
  ORDER BY cod_art, timestamp
""".format(cod_art_list=format_strings)

cursor.execute(query_sql, query_params)
```

---

Explanation:

Say `cod_art_int` is this list of integer values:

```
cod_art_int = [10, 20, 30]
```

In order to use those values in the `cod_art IN (...)` part of the query, you need to add a `%s` for each one. That is done by:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(cod_art_int))
```

Which can be broken down to:

```
step_one = ['%s'] * len(cod_art_int)
# ['%s', '%s', '%s']

format_strings = ','.join(step_one)
# '%s,%s,%s'
```

When you build the final query string, you replace `{cod_art_list}` with `format_strings`:

```
query_sql = """
    SELECT cod_art, price_EU, price_third_country 
    FROM lt_gamma_articles
    WHERE cod_art IN ({cod_art_list}) AND cod_store = %s 
    ORDER BY cod_art, timestamp
""".format(cod_art_list=format_strings)
```

And you get the query string:

```sql
SELECT cod_art, price_EU, price_third_country 
FROM lt_gamma_articles
WHERE cod_art IN (%s,%s,%s) AND cod_store = %s 
ORDER BY cod_art, timestamp
```

Then your query parameters will be safely substituted within the query to replace the `%s`s. You build up the parameter list to correspond to the `%s`s. Since `cod_art IN (%s,%s,%s)` is first, you add that to the list first, followed by the value for `cod_store` (`int(shop)` which I'm going to say is 456):

```
query_params = list(cod_art_int)
# [10, 20, 30] 

query_params.append(int(shop))
# [10, 20, 30, 456]
```

In the end you execute the query with its parameters:

```
cursor.execute(query_sql, query_params)
```

Comment: Bingo! It worked!
Thank you very much!
Do you have a source like a link or something for me to understand this ?

Comment: @AlbertS. I don't have a good link, but see my update to the answer.