# Can't get python tuple as input in WHERE IN SQL clause?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

**Python Code:**

query is a UPDATE query, and the error simply states there is some problem with the tuple,which is passed as an argument to the IN Clause

*pyList is Python List, DBOBJ is connection object*

```
pyTuple = tuple(pyList)
print(pyTuple)

pyTupleSQLFormat = DBOBJ.string_literal(pyTuple)
print(pyTupleSQLFormat)

query = "UPDATE seats SET isReserved = 1 WHERE screen_name='{}' AND seat_number IN %s".format(screenname)
args = (pyTupleSQLFormat,)
CurOBJ.execute(query,args)
```

**Console Output: Python**

```
('B1', 'B2', 'A6', 'A7')
b"'(\\'B1\\', \\'B2\\', \\'A6\\', \\'A7\\')'"
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\\'(\\\\\\'B1\\\\\\', \\\\\\'B2\\\\\\', \\\\\\'A6\\\\\\', \\\\\\'A7\\\\\\')\\''' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string_literal(...)` appears to be preparing the object for insertion into a char/text field, not stringifying it in a way that could be appended to a query.

You can pass the tuple contents in as additional parameters for your query by [dynamically building parameter placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416/833881). This has the additional advantage of using parameterization to avoid SQL injection and related problems.

```
screen_name = "example"
seat_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

args = tuple([screen_name] + seat_numbers)

query = """
UPDATE 
    seats 
SET 
    isReserved = 1 
WHERE 
    screen_name=%s AND 
    seat_number IN ({placeholders})
""".format(
    placeholders=",".join(["%s"] * len(seat_numbers)),
)
print(query)
print(args)

cursor.execute(query, args)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks @kungphu