# Python3 MySQLdb Query Does Not Execute

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm using MySQLdb in Python3 to execute some queries. One of which I have a list of `user_ids` and want to delete from my user table based off of them.

When I execute the query I get a warning from MySQLdb:

```
Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '108, 114, 109, 115'")
```

The query attempted to be executed is:

```
DELETE FROM user
WHERE id IN (108, 114, 109, 115);
```

My code looks like the following:

```
cur.execute(get_users)
users = cur.fetchall()
users = [item[0] for item in users]
users = ", ".join(str(user) for user in users)

cur.execute(delete_query, [users])
```

I have also tried to do the following, it results in no warning however checking my database I can still see those users existing:

```
users = ", ".join("\'{}\'".format(user) for user in users)
```

The following works perfectly, however isn't secure:
     cur.execute(delete_query.format(users))

And yes, I am executing a `db.commit()` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach has worked for me. The `users` list will be going directly to the MySQL driver so injection is not an issue:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(users))
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN (%s)" % format_strings,
                tuple(users))
```

Comment: Just found this from the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/589416/1327636

It seems to work for me as well, thanks!