# Python3 + DB: "Select * from `table` where `field` IN (...) AND `field2` = '...'"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, mysql-python

Using Python3 and the

```
cursor.execute(sql, {key1: val1, key2: val2})
```

syntax, I want to execute a safe (SQL-injection-proof) query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`

WHERE 

a = %(fieldA)s AND b IN (%(fieldB)s)
```

Basically, I am looking for the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause) but with the Python3 syntax and using multiple fields.

If I use [@nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17160/nosklo)'s answer:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(list_of_ids))
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM foo.bar WHERE baz IN (%s)" % format_strings,
tuple(list_of_ids))
```

1) How do I implement this double formatting syntax (`format_strings, tuple(list_of_ids))`) using the dictionary syntax:

```
cursor.execute(sql, {'field': 'val'})
```

2) and how do I implement it in my case when I have multiple fields:

```
cursor.execute(sql, {'x': 'myList', 'y':myOtherVar'})
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I just found it out:

```
myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
myStr = "d"

sql = """SELECT * FROM `table`

WHERE 

a = %(myStr)s AND b IN %(myList)s"""

cursor.execute(sql, {
    myList: myList,
    myStr: myStr
})
```

Have been trying with `IN (%(myStr)s)` before instead of  `IN %(myStr)s`.

I still don't understand why some people claim we must use tuples in that case, as the list worked just perfectly fine.