# How to create a new column from a dictionary that its values are keys for sets?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a subset of the main dataframe. The whole columns are lister in the dictionary below

```
age_groups_type procedureschoice=aortic_valve_repair    procedureschoice=arterial_switch
0   Pediatrics  False                                   True
1   Pediatrics  False                                   True
2   Pediatrics  False                                   True
3   Adults      True                                    False
4   Adults      True                                    False
5   Pediatrics  False                                   True
6   Adults      True                                    False
7   Pediatrics  False                                   True
8   Adults      True                                    False
9   Pediatrics  False                                   True
```

This dictionary contains the category of each operation whether being 'Aortic', 'Mitral'. etc. and their corresponding `age_group_type` whether being 'Adults' or 'pediatrics' (children)

```
{'Adults': {'Aortic': {'procedureschoice=aortic_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=arch_replacement',
   'procedureschoice=ascending_aortic_replacement',
   'procedureschoice=avrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=avrstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=bentall',
   'procedureschoice=freestyle',
   'procedureschoice=homograft_aortic_root_replacement',
   'procedureschoice=ross',
   'procedureschoice=valve-sparing_aortic_root_replacement'},
  'Mitral': {'procedureschoice=mitral_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=mvrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=mvrstented_bioprosthesis'},
  'Tricuspid': {'procedureschoice=tricuspid_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=tvrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=tvrstented_bioprosthesis'},
  'CABG': {'procedureschoice=cabg'},
  'Myectomy': {'procedureschoice=myectomy'},
  'GUCH': {'procedureschoice=alcapa_repair',
   'procedureschoice=arterial_switch',
   'procedureschoice=asd_closure',
   'procedureschoice=atrial_septectomy',
   'procedureschoice=atrial_switchmustard',
   'procedureschoice=av_canal_repairpartial',
   'procedureschoice=av_canal_repairtransitional',
   'procedureschoice=central_shunt',
   'procedureschoice=coarctectomy_with_extended_end-to-end_anastomosis',
   'procedureschoice=cor-triatriatum_repair',
   'procedureschoice=coronary_av_fistula_repair',
   'procedureschoice=extra-anatomical_bypass_of_coa',
   'procedureschoice=fallot_repair',
   'procedureschoice=fontan',
   'procedureschoice=glenn',
   'procedureschoice=lpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=mbt_shunt',
   'procedureschoice=mpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=pa_banding',
   'procedureschoice=papvc_repair',
   'procedureschoice=pda_closure',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_trans-annular_patch',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementfreestyle',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementhomograft',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valvotomy',
   'procedureschoice=rastelli',
   'procedureschoice=relief_of_rvoto',
   'procedureschoice=resection_of_subaortic_membrane',
   'procedureschoice=rpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=rupture_sinus_of_valsalva_repair',
   'procedureschoice=rvot_patch',
   'procedureschoice=supravalvular_as_repair',
   'procedureschoice=vascular_ring_repair',
   'procedureschoice=vsd_closure'}},
 'Pediatrics': {'VSD': {'procedureschoice=vsd_closure'},
  'TGA': {'procedureschoice=arterial_switch',
   'procedureschoice=atrial_switchmustard',
   'procedureschoice=rastelli'},
  'Arch': {'procedureschoice=arch_repair',
   'procedureschoice=coarctectomy_with_extended_end-to-end_anastomosis',
   'procedureschoice=extra-anatomical_bypass_of_coa'},
  'Canal': {'procedureschoice=av_canal_repaircomplete',
   'procedureschoice=av_canal_repairpartial',
   'procedureschoice=av_canal_repairtransitional'},
  'Valvular': {'procedureschoice=aortic_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=avrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=avrstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=bentall',
   'procedureschoice=freestyle',
   'procedureschoice=homograft_aortic_root_replacement',
   'procedureschoice=maze_procedure',
   'procedureschoice=mitral_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=mvrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=mvrstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=ross',
   'procedureschoice=tricuspid_valve_repair',
   'procedureschoice=tvrmechanical',
   'procedureschoice=tvrstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=valve-sparing_aortic_root_replacement'},
  'RVOT_PA': {'procedureschoice=fallot_repair',
   'procedureschoice=lpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=mpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_trans-annular_patch',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementfreestyle',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementhomograft',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valve_replacementstented_bioprosthesis',
   'procedureschoice=pulmonary_valvotomy',
   'procedureschoice=relief_of_rvoto',
   'procedureschoice=rpa_reconstruction',
   'procedureschoice=rvot_patch'},
  'Palliative': {'procedureschoice=atrial_septectomy',
   'procedureschoice=central_shunt',
   'procedureschoice=dks',
   'procedureschoice=first_stage_switchpab,_bts',
   'procedureschoice=fontan',
   'procedureschoice=glenn',
   'procedureschoice=mbt_shunt',
   'procedureschoice=pa_banding'}}}
```

what I need is to create a new column `procedure_group` that filled with the dictionary keys `['Aortic', 'Mitral', 'Tricuspid', 'CABG', 'Myectomy', 'GUCH']` for adult patients and `['VSD', 'TGA', 'Arch', 'Canal', 'Valvular', 'RVOT_PA', 'Palliative']` for pediatric patients.
I tried this

```
def code_map(row):
    for key in code.keys():
        for i in code[key].keys():
            for k in list(code[key][i]):
                if row[row['age_groups_type'] == 'Adults' & row[k] == True]:
                    return i
                elif row[row['age_groups_type'] == 'Pediatrics' & row[k] == True]:
                    return i
df['procedure_group'] = df.apply(code_map, axis=1)
```

and this

```
def code_map(df):
    for col in df:
        for i in range(len(adult_list)):
            if code["Adults"][i][col] == True:
                return code["Adults"][i]
        for i in range(len(pediatrics_list)):
            if code["Pediatrics"][i][col] == True:
                return code["Pediatrics"][i]
df['procedure_group'] = df.apply(code_map(df), axis=1)
```

and other solutions, but all trials failed.

The final output will be like this

```
age_groups_type procedureschoice=aortic_valve_repair    procedureschoice=arterial_switch       procedure_group
0   Pediatrics  False                                   True               TGA
1   Pediatrics  True                                    False              Aortic
2   Pediatrics  False                                   True               TGA
3   Adults      True                                    False              Aortic
4   Adults      True                                    False              Aortic
5   Pediatrics  False                                   True               TGA
6   Adults      True                                    False              Aortic
7   Pediatrics  False                                   True               TGA
8   Adults      True                                    False              Aortic
9   Pediatrics  False                                   True               TGA
```

**The logic I'm thinking of is if, in each row, the procedure is `True` and the patient is Adults, return the dictionary values corresponding this row.**
How can I do this?

Comment: i think you just need `isin` how are you constructing your dataframe from the dict? additionally, can you supply an intended output?

Comment: the output is added @Datanovice

Comment: @Datanovice can you please provide a simple code that uses  ```isin```

Comment: i can't reproduce your dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885071/using-isin-in-a-sql-query-with-a-python-list