# Python type tuple cannot be converted when selecting from Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to select a query in mysql where the employee_id is a number from a list of values. Below is the query that I thought should work.

```
import mysql.connector
employee_id_list = [10,15]
sql = "select value, employee_id " \
"from employee_table " \
"where employee_id in %s "    

df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn,params=[tuple(employee_id_list)])
```

However, it produces the following error:

> Python type tuple cannot be converted

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Is `tupple` a typo? do not name your list as `list`

Comment: I suggest looking at https://github.com/kennethreitz/records which might make your development easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)