# Correct format of list parameters in composed sql query

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to execute a sql query with a joined list as a parameter .
I already established a database connection and I want to have a query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE
WHERE ( name IN ('name1','name2') );
```

So I want to pass the list as a parameter , and the variable filters is the variable that has the right format stored , but not actually used.
The code that was supposed to do that is :

```py
my_list = ['name1', 'name2']
filters = ",".join(("'{}'".format(key) for key in my_list))

q = sql.SQL('''SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN ({}) );''')
       .format(sql.SQL(', ')
       .join(sql.Placeholder() * len(my_list)))

cur = self.con.cursor()

query = q.as_string(context=self.con)
cur.execute(q)
results = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
```

The string **query** is :

> 'SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN (%s, %s) );'

, which seems right.
But there is an error bout the the escape character and I cannot find a way around. 
Last , I have to use the placeholder and not a simple
     ".... where  name = {}".format() 
solution , mostly for security reasons.
Any help ?

EDIT: 
I tried all the suggestions and they all give me the Syntax Error :

> 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," 
>   LINE 1: ....MY_TABLE WHERE (name IN (?,?)) ... 
>   ..................................................................... ^'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE (name IN (?,?))",my_list[0], my_list[1])
```

Comment: You can apply unpacking there `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE (name IN (?,?))", *my_list)`

Comment: This is a solution for a list with only 2 items , but the length of the list can and it will be different in every call . So how would this work for a different length in every call ?

Answer (score 0):

```
placeholder = '?'
placeholders = ', '.join(placeholder for unused in mylist)
query = "SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE (name IN (%s))" % placeholders
list = ",".join(my_list)    
cursor.execute(query, list)
```

Comment: I get an exeption : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Sorry I miss one more line, check it now

Comment: This was supposed to work , I get the same error as the beggining :syntax error at syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...E.MY_TABLE name IN (?, ?) AND

Comment: try now with the last change

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `",".join(my_list)`, this will concatenate your table with "', '" as a separator:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
joined_list = "', '".join(my_list)   # Returns: "name1,name2,name3"

formatted = f"SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN ('{joined_list}') )"
print(formatted) # Result: "SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4') )"
```

EDIT: Here is a better solution to avoid SQL injection

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
place_holders = "?," * (len(my_list) -1) + "?"

formatted = f"SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN ({place_holders}) )"
print(formatted) # Result: "SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE.MY_TABLE WHERE ( name IN (?,?,?,?) )"
```

Comment: This gives me an syntax error because for the query to be successfull , the names have to be single quoted as : 'name1' . 
This will work only if the joined_list is :

    filters = ",".join(("'{}'".format(key) for key in my_list))

But the question in that case is  if it is safe from sql injection,etc.

Comment: Nope, it's not safe. I added another way to do the placeholders thing to the answer, so you can unpack the list to pass it as arguments when executing it

Comment: So , now I get a TypeError , propably because doing something wrong , "function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)" . 
I unpack the list as : cur.execute(q, *my_list)

Comment: Ouch, I missed that, when you execute the query just pass a tuple to it, it will get unpacked during executing. it should be like cur.execute(q, tuple(my_list)) in your case

Comment: I get the same SyntaxError that I was getting since the beginning: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ....MY_TABLE WHERE (name IN (?,?)) ...
                                                             ^