# Python MySQL SELECT WHERE with list

Tags: python, mysql, performance, select, coding-efficiency

I have the following Python MySQL code.

```
cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE col1=%s AND col2=%s', (val1, val2))
ids = cursor.fetchall()

for id in ids:
    cursor.execute('SELECT record_key FROM table2 WHERE id=%s limit 1', (id[0], ))
    record_keys = cursor.fetchall()
    print(record_keys[0][0])
```

How can I make this more efficient? I am using 5.5.60-MariaDB and Python 2.7.5. I have approximately 350 million entries in table1 and 15 million entries in table2.

Comment: `cursor.execute('SELECT record_key FROM table2 WHERE id IN %s limit 1', (id[0], ))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happily, you can do this in a single query using a LEFT JOIN.

```py
cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    "SELECT t1.id, t2.record_key FROM table1 t1 "
    "LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) "
    "WHERE t1.col1=%s AND t2.col2=%s",
    (val1, val2),
)
for id, record_key in cursor.fetchall():
    pass  # do something...
```