# Constructing a parametrized sql query with variable number of args

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Using MySQLDB, I am able to do database operations. But, I got stuck at one point where I need to construct a query having a `where objectid in (variable no. of args)` condition.
Since args are variable, I am unable to construct a query having matching number of `%s`.
Normally, I do this for a query like below:

```
select * from table where objectid in (args1, args2, args3, args4)
```

For query above, I would go like this and pass the relevant tuple having 4 members:

```
select * from table where objectid in (%s, %s, %s, %s)
```

But, for a query like below, how do I match the number of `%s` for variable number of args:

```
select * from table where objectid in (args1, args2, args3, args4...)
```

Only thing I could think of doing is to create a tuple having as many number of `%s` as the args, in a for loop and then add it using string concatenation. Would this method be a wrong choice?

Comment: I believe that is accomplished [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause), Mr.President.

Comment: @JNevill Mission accomplished, thanks for your services!