# Pass list values to MySQL query using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I want to pass list values along with other parameter values. following is my scenario. I want to pass multiple values for column "Code" and want to pass single value to "Continent" column.

```
param = [('AFG', 'IND'),'Asia']
query = "select * from country where Code in (%s) AND Continent = %s"
cursor.execute(query,param)
```

while executing in Python, I am getting following error.

> Failed to execute Query: Failed processing format-parameters; Python
>   'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: It is strange, i put your code in mariadb and it give a total different error:   (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is the `WHERE IN` clause, which isn't really amenable to being parameterized.  One option generates an `IN` clause with the exact number of placeholders in your list:

```
codes = ('AFG', 'IND')
continent = 'Asia'
params = codes + (continent,)
where_in = ','.join(['%s'] * len(codes))
sql = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE Code IN (%s) AND Continent = %s" % (where_in, '%s')
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

To see what the above script actually did, lets look at the various parts:

```
print(where_in)
print(sql)

%s,%s
SELECT * FROM country WHERE Code IN (%s,%s) AND Continent = %s
```

The trick here is that we actually use a `%s` placeholder *twice*, once for the Python string, and a second time for the SQL query string.  Also, we bind a single level tuple containing all bound values:

```
('AFG', 'IND', 'ASIA')
```

Comment: @MaxMuster I think you meant to drop this comment under the OP.  I have given a correct answer assuming the OP's query be correct.

Comment: sorry I see now his query had it also.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I have a question. If I have more than one column has list values, how to pass them? I mean If I want to pass Code and Continent as list values, how to pass them.

Comment: Then going by answer you would need two `where_in` variables, one for each `WHERE IN` clause, and you would have to substitute and then bind both of them.  I won't update my answer, but if you still have doubts feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

first you split the list and then you split the tuple.

```
param = [('AFG', 'IND'),'Asia']
p1,p2=param[0]
query = "select * from country where Code in ('%s','%s') AND Continent = %s" % (p1,p2,param[1])
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, and the `%s` placeholders should _not_ be in single quotes (which partially defeats the purpose of using a statement).  Also, you are hardcoding `WHERE IN` plus two items, when in fact future readers of this question might want a solution for an arbitrary number.