# How to insert a string list in a python MySQLDB VALUE clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

This is similar with [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284) and [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645), but their list's elements are all integer.

```py
param = []
param.append(post.title)
param.append(post.count_vote)
param.append(post.last_reply_time)
param.append(post.last_replyer_id)
param.append(post.poster_id)
param.append(post.content)
param.append(post.plain_content)
param.append(post.relate_unit)

query = "INSERT INTO post (title, countVote, lastReplyTime, lastReplyerId, posterId, content, plainContent, relateUnit) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}');".format(*param)

cursor.execute(query)
```

The elements have many types such as int, str and None. What stucks me is the string type, the string may contain `'` and `"`. I just simply replaced `'` with `"` before. However, I accidently saw some C code snippet like `char ch = 'a';` in content field. `'` replacement will disobey the syntax.

I want to know is there a way to insert string without modification? I come across the idea to replace `'` with `\'`, is that a good idea?

I also try to replace `{0}` etc. in the query string with `?`

```
query = "INSERT INTO post (title, countVote, lastReplyTime, lastReplyerId, posterId, content, plainContent, relateUnit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

cursor.execute(query, tuple(param))
# cursor.execute(query, [param,])
```

Both give me the error

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: What kind of MySQL connector are you using? If you're using `mysql-connector-python` you should use `format` or `pyformat` style for the notation of your variables. Can you narrow down which variable is causing the problem? What type is it?

Comment: @yvesonline Thank you for your comment, I'm using [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#mysqldb). I don't quite understand what do you mean in `Can you narrow down which variable is causing the problem?`. If you are asking about my question, it is the content variable whose type is string. If you are asking about the error I paste at the bottom, I can't figure that out.

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if this brings you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info that you're using [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/).

- Try using `format` for [parameter marker formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), i.e. `%s`, `%d`, and so on, see below, I assumed everything is a string which is most likely wrong.
- Make sure to escape `%`, see the doc: `Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%.` do this wherever applicable, I did it examplory for `post.content` & `post.plain_content`.

```
query = "INSERT INTO post (title, countVote, lastReplyTime, lastReplyerId, posterId, content, plainContent, relateUnit) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
cursor.execute(query,post.title, post.count_vote, post.last_reply_time, post.last_replyer_id, post.poster_id, post.content.replace("%", "%%"), post.plain_content.replace("%", "%%"), post.relate_unit)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can the post.count_vote etc. be passed as list? Honestly speaking, post object has 30+ fields. I have ommitted unrelated one in my question. I also encapsulate cursor.execute to a function, so that I could use it in other object like comment, reply.

Comment: I try to replace `?` with `%s`, but the program is crashed at `'` too. I decide just to replace `'` with `\'` to save my day.