# Creating sqlquery in python with IN clause

Tags: sql, python-3.x

i have file and i am reading the file in list using python. then these needs to be used in sqlquery in the IN clause. File is read using a functionreadCsv & contents are stored in list(file may have more than 10k records at times) and now i have to pass this list to sqlquery in value1 & value2 & so on. any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
 def readCsv():
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin1') as file:
               csvreader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in csvreader:
                     nlist.append(row)
                       
 if __name__ == '__main__':
       nlist = [] 
       readCsv()

       sqlquery = "select col1,col2 from tablename where col3 in ('value1',,'value2')
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why did you use two commas in `where col3 in ('value1',,'value2')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may join the elements in the list to form a string with comma separated values and use that string as a parameter for the execute() command. Note that the parameter has to be a tuple.
Something like this may work for you:

```
values = ','.join(['%s'] * len(nlist))
cursor.execute("SELECT col1,col2 FROM tablename WHERE col3 IN (%s)" % values, tuple(nlist))
```

Please look at the accepted answers in these questions below as they offer similar working solutions:
[imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

[python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)