# Why is MySQL Connector disconnecting during my loop?

Tags: python, mysql, loops, connection

I a unsure why my connection is giving me an error while I loop through my table to search for elements of my list:

```py
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='####',host='####',database='###', allow_local_infile=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")

index= 0

for i in range(0, len(listdates)):
    date= listdates[i]
    print(date)
    try:
        query = ("SELECT * FROM search WHERE time= %s;", (date,))
        cursor.execute(query)
        row= cursor.fetchall()
        if not row:
           index = i
           break
  
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("did not return row")
```

I am not sure what the issue is. My connection is fine since when I execute the query outside the loop I have no issue. In the larger code this will go in, I have no issue looping through my queries. I don't know what is wrong.

error:
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: Connection not available.

I attempted to use cursor.close() in the loop. I also have tried using "
with conn.cursor() as cursor:" outside of of the loop.

Comment: i don't know how may elements you have, but you bombard the server with too many requests and it will cause problem. for that you need a IN clause see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysql-in-clause

Answer (score 1):

The `execute` method takes one or two arguments, two arguments being required when the first argument, your SQL statement as a string, has `%s` placeholders. In this case the second argument should be a `tuple` or a `list` with the actual values to replace the `%s` placeholders:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM search WHERE time = %s", (date,))
```

The second argument is a tuple in this case. But you had the equivalent of:

```py
cursor.execute(("SELECT * FROM search WHERE time= %s;", (date,)))
```

I have taken the liberty of replacing variable `query` with its actual value in the above method call. You are passing a *single* argument that is a tuple. This is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few thing you could check on and improve:

**Timeout**: MySQL's `wait_timeout` might be closing inactive connections.

- **Fix**: Increase `wait_timeout` or periodically run a `SELECT 1` query to keep the connection alive.

**Query Formatting**: Instead of:

```py
query = ("SELECT * FROM search WHERE time= %s;", (date,))
```

Use:

```py
query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE time= %s"
cursor.execute(query, (date,))
```

**Reconnect**: Set `autocommit` to `True` and use `conn.ping(reconnect=True)` to auto-reconnect.

**Server Logs**: Check MySQL server logs for errors or restarts.

**Network**: Ensure a stable network connection if MySQL is remote.

**Resource Limits**: Ensure MySQL isn't hitting max connections.

**Manage Cursors**: Close cursors after use, but no need to close/reopen for each loop iteration.

**Context Managers**: Use `with conn.cursor() as cursor:` outside the loop for better resource management.

Remember to isolate the issue by testing with smaller data or adding logs to pinpoint the exact problem.